# Select cast with max +1 from textstring

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I'm using this code but i get Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'o' to data type int.

my columns contain example

```
o01
o02
o13

select cast('o'+(max(right(panelname, 2 )+1))as varchar(50))
```

Should use Convert thats why i get this errror?

It was syntax error, Solved Like this,but now in values >10 i want to take tis result o06, now i take o6

```
select 'o' + cast(max(right(panelname, 2) + 1) as varchar(50))
```

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.  Also, although not relevant to the question, you should upgrade to a more recent version of SQL Server -- SQL Server 2000 has been unsupported for *years*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding one to a string.  `1` is a number so `+` is interpreted as addition rather than concatenation.

Perhaps you intend:

```
select cast('o' + (max(right(panelname, 2 ) + '1')) as varchar(50))
```

Alternatively, you might want:

```
select 'o' + cast(max(right(panelname, 2) + 1) as varchar(50))
```

This assume that the last two characters of `panelname` are digits.

Comment: That code adds a value '1' in the end of my text. I want to add max +1

Comment: Oh! so it was syntax error. Thank you it works! But in values >10 i want to take tis result o06, now i take o6

Comment: @user6615498 . . . You should probably ask another question.